# handling nested json in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to handle nested json with pandas using `read_json`, but I am getting repeated entries like shown here:

```
contributors_enabled               2013-11-30 20:48:42   
created_at                         2013-11-30 20:48:42   
default_profile                    2013-11-30 20:48:42   
default_profile_image              2013-11-30 20:48:42   
description                        2013-11-30 20:48:42   
favourites_count                   2013-11-30 20:48:42   
follow_request_sent                2013-11-30 20:48:42   
...
                                                                           source  \
contributors_enabled                <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...   
created_at                          <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...   
default_profile                     <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...   
default_profile_image               <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...   
description                         <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...   
favourites_count                    <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...   
follow_request_sent...
```

how can this be changed to correct format?

I am using the following code:

```py
for line in gzip.open("/home/amrith/shared/twitter-stream/tweets-1385844523.txt.gz"):
    tweet = read_json(line)
    print(tweet)
```

The input line looks like:

```
{'contributors': None,
 'coordinates': None,
 'created_at': 'Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013',
 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'urls': [], 'user_mentions': []},
 'favorite_count': 0,
 'favorited': False,
 'filter_level': 'medium',
 'geo': None,
 'id': 12345,
 'id_str': '12345',
 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
 'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
 'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
 'lang': 'es',
 'place': None,
 'retweet_count': 0,
 'retweeted': False,
 'source': '<a href="http:\\/\\/blackberry.com\\/twitter" '
           'rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry®<\\/a>',
 'text': 'Todo va a estar bn :D',
 'truncated': False,
 'user': {'contributors_enabled': False,
          'created_at': 'Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012',
          'default_profile': False,
          'default_profile_image': False,
          'description': 'No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, '
                         'tengo muchos errores también lo se pero me acepto y '
                         'me amo como soy.',
          'favourites_count': 218,
          'follow_request_sent': None,
          'followers_count': 71,
          'following': None,
          'friends_count': 64,
          'geo_enabled': True,
          'id': 54321,
          'id_str': '54321',
          'is_translator': False,
          'lang': 'es',
          'listed_count': 0,
          'location': '',
          'name': 'xxxxx',
          'notifications': None,
          'profile_background_color': 'DBE9ED',
          'profile_background_image_url': 'http:\\/\\/a0.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/378800000116209016\\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg',
          'profile_background_image_url_https': 'https:\\/\\/si0.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/378800000116209016\\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg',
          'profile_background_tile': True,
          'profile_banner_url': 'https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/483470963\\/1385144720',
          'profile_image_url': 'http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/378800000736604157\\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg',
          'profile_image_url_https': 'https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/378800000736604157\\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg',
          'profile_link_color': '9D1DCF',
          'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'FFFFFF',
          'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'E6F6F9',
          'profile_text_color': '333333',
          'profile_use_background_image': True,
          'protected': False,
          'screen_name': 'xxxxx',
          'statuses_count': 10407,
          'time_zone': 'Central Time (US & Canada)',
          'url': None,
          'utc_offset': -21600,
          'verified': False}}
```

Comment: Please post a representative sample of the source data and the commands you're using to read it in.

Comment: @PaulH I have edited and added necessary details

Comment: OK -- I removed that JSON data -- it had wayyy too much personal information of a third party. So here's what you need to do: mock up or edit some anonymous, minimal data that reproduces your problem, and then write some code that generates that data, reads it in, and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me what is your end goal? Is it importing data to Pandas to do some heavy analytic job or just using Pandas to work with stream of JSON data from Twitter?

Answer (score 2):

### Use recursion to flatten the nested `dicts`

- [Thinking Recursively in Python](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)
- [Flattening JSON objects in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)
- [flatten](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten)
- The following function, will be used to flatten `_source_list`

```py
def flatten_json(nested_json: dict, exclude: list=['']) -> dict:
    """
    Flatten a list of nested dicts.
    """
    out = dict()
    def flatten(x: (list, dict, str), name: str='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    flatten(x[a], f'{name}{a}_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out
```

### Data:

- To create the dataset, I used the given data, three times

  1. `data` is a `json`

```py
data = {'stuff': [{"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013","id":12345,"id_str":"12345","text":"Todo va a estar bn :D","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":False,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":54321,"id_str":"54321","name":"xxxxx","screen_name":"xxxxx","location":"","url":null,"description":"No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores tambi\u00e9n lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.","protected":false,"followers_count":71,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012","favourites_count":218,"utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":True,"verified":False,"statuses_count":10407,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":False,"is_translator":False,"profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720","profile_link_color":"9D1DCF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":True,"default_profile":False,"default_profile_image":False,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":False,"retweeted":False,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"es"},
                  {"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013","id":12345,"id_str":"12345","text":"Todo va a estar bn :D","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":False,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":54321,"id_str":"54321","name":"xxxxx","screen_name":"xxxxx","location":"","url":null,"description":"No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores tambi\u00e9n lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.","protected":false,"followers_count":71,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012","favourites_count":218,"utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":True,"verified":False,"statuses_count":10407,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":False,"is_translator":False,"profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720","profile_link_color":"9D1DCF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":True,"default_profile":False,"default_profile_image":False,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":False,"retweeted":False,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"es"},
                  {"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013","id":12345,"id_str":"12345","text":"Todo va a estar bn :D","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":False,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":54321,"id_str":"54321","name":"xxxxx","screen_name":"xxxxx","location":"","url":null,"description":"No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores tambi\u00e9n lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.","protected":false,"followers_count":71,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012","favourites_count":218,"utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":True,"verified":False,"statuses_count":10407,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":False,"is_translator":False,"profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720","profile_link_color":"9D1DCF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":True,"default_profile":False,"default_profile_image":False,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":False,"retweeted":False,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"es"}]}
```

2. `data` is a `list` of `dicts`

```py
data = [{"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013","id":12345,"id_str":"12345","text":"Todo va a estar bn :D","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":False,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":54321,"id_str":"54321","name":"xxxxx","screen_name":"xxxxx","location":"","url":null,"description":"No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores tambi\u00e9n lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.","protected":false,"followers_count":71,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012","favourites_count":218,"utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":True,"verified":False,"statuses_count":10407,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":False,"is_translator":False,"profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720","profile_link_color":"9D1DCF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":True,"default_profile":False,"default_profile_image":False,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":False,"retweeted":False,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"es"},
        {"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013","id":12345,"id_str":"12345","text":"Todo va a estar bn :D","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":False,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":54321,"id_str":"54321","name":"xxxxx","screen_name":"xxxxx","location":"","url":null,"description":"No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores tambi\u00e9n lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.","protected":false,"followers_count":71,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012","favourites_count":218,"utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":True,"verified":False,"statuses_count":10407,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":False,"is_translator":False,"profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720","profile_link_color":"9D1DCF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":True,"default_profile":False,"default_profile_image":False,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":False,"retweeted":False,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"es"},
        {"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013","id":12345,"id_str":"12345","text":"Todo va a estar bn :D","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":False,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":54321,"id_str":"54321","name":"xxxxx","screen_name":"xxxxx","location":"","url":null,"description":"No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores tambi\u00e9n lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.","protected":false,"followers_count":71,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012","favourites_count":218,"utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":True,"verified":False,"statuses_count":10407,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":False,"is_translator":False,"profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720","profile_link_color":"9D1DCF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":True,"default_profile":False,"default_profile_image":False,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":False,"retweeted":False,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"es"}]
```

#### Using `flatten_json`:

1. if `data` is a `json`, as above

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data['stuff'])
```

2. if `data` is a `list` of `dicts`, as above

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data)
```

#### Output:

```py
                     created_at     id id_str                   text                                                                                  source  truncated in_reply_to_status_id in_reply_to_status_id_str in_reply_to_user_id in_reply_to_user_id_str in_reply_to_screen_name  user_id user_id_str user_name user_screen_name user_location user_url                                                                                                         user_description  user_protected  user_followers_count  user_friends_count  user_listed_count                 user_created_at  user_favourites_count  user_utc_offset              user_time_zone  user_geo_enabled  user_verified  user_statuses_count user_lang  user_contributors_enabled  user_is_translator user_profile_background_color                                                                            user_profile_background_image_url                                                                        user_profile_background_image_url_https  user_profile_background_tile                                                                                    user_profile_image_url                                                                               user_profile_image_url_https                                          user_profile_banner_url user_profile_link_color user_profile_sidebar_border_color user_profile_sidebar_fill_color user_profile_text_color  user_profile_use_background_image  user_default_profile  user_default_profile_image user_following user_follow_request_sent user_notifications   geo coordinates place contributors  retweet_count  favorite_count  favorited  retweeted filter_level lang
 Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013  12345  12345  Todo va a estar bn :D  <a href="http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry®<\/a>      False                  None                      None                None                    None                    None    54321       54321     xxxxx            xxxxx                   None  No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores también lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.           False                    71                  64                  0  Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012                    218           -21600  Central Time (US & Canada)              True          False                10407        es                      False               False                        DBE9ED  http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg  https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg                          True  http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg  https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg  https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720                  9D1DCF                            FFFFFF                          E6F6F9                  333333                               True                 False                       False           None                     None               None  None        None  None         None              0               0      False      False       medium   es
 Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013  12345  12345  Todo va a estar bn :D  <a href="http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry®<\/a>      False                  None                      None                None                    None                    None    54321       54321     xxxxx            xxxxx                   None  No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores también lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.           False                    71                  64                  0  Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012                    218           -21600  Central Time (US & Canada)              True          False                10407        es                      False               False                        DBE9ED  http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg  https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg                          True  http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg  https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg  https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720                  9D1DCF                            FFFFFF                          E6F6F9                  333333                               True                 False                       False           None                     None               None  None        None  None         None              0               0      False      False       medium   es
 Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013  12345  12345  Todo va a estar bn :D  <a href="http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry®<\/a>      False                  None                      None                None                    None                    None    54321       54321     xxxxx            xxxxx                   None  No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores también lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.           False                    71                  64                  0  Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012                    218           -21600  Central Time (US & Canada)              True          False                10407        es                      False               False                        DBE9ED  http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg  https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg                          True  http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg  https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg  https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720                  9D1DCF                            FFFFFF                          E6F6F9                  333333                               True                 False                       False           None                     None               None  None        None  None         None              0               0      False      False       medium   es
```