# How to flatten a nested JSON recursively, with flatten_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, recursion

#### This question is specific to using `flatten_json` from [GitHub Repo: flatten](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten)

- The package is on pypi [flatten-json](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/) and can be installed with `pip install flatten-json`
- This question is specific to the following component of the package:

```py
def flatten_json(nested_json: dict, exclude: list=[''], sep: str='_') -> dict:
    """
    Flatten a list of nested dicts.
    """
    out = dict()
    def flatten(x: (list, dict, str), name: str='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    flatten(x[a], f'{name}{a}{sep}')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}{sep}')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out
```

#### Use recursion to flatten nested `dicts`

- [Thinking Recursively in Python](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)
- [Flattening JSON objects in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)

#### How nested can `data` be?:

- `flatten_json` has been used to unpack a file that ended up being over 100000 columns

#### Can the flattened JSON, be unflattened?:

- Yes, this question doesn't cover that.  However, if you install the `flatten` package, there is an `unflatten` method, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### How to flatten a `JSON` or `dict` is a common question, to which there are many answers.

- This answer focuses on using `flatten_json` to recursively flatten a nested `dict` or `JSON`.

### Assumptions:

- This answer assumes you already have the `JSON` or `dict` loaded into some variable (e.g. file, api, etc.)

  - In this case we will use `data`

### How is `data` loaded into `flatten_json`:

- It accepts a `dict`, as shown by the function type hint.

#### The most common forms of `data`:

- Just a dict: `{}`

  - `flatten_json(data)`
- List of dicts: `[{}, {}, {}]`

  - `[flatten_json(x) for x in data]`
- JSON with with top level keys, where the values repeat: `{1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}}`

  - `[flatten_json(data[key]) for key in data]`
- Other

  - `{'key': [{}, {}, {}]}`: `[flatten_json(x) for x in data['key']]`

### Practical Examples:

- I typically flatten `data` into a `pandas.DataFrame` for further analysis.

  - Load `pandas` with `import pandas as pd`
- `flatten_json` returns a `dict`, which can be saved directly using the `csv` packages.

---

#### Data 1:

```py
{
    "id": 1,
    "class": "c1",
    "owner": "myself",
    "metadata": {
        "m1": {
            "value": "m1_1",
            "timestamp": "d1"
        },
        "m2": {
            "value": "m1_2",
            "timestamp": "d2"
        },
        "m3": {
            "value": "m1_3",
            "timestamp": "d3"
        },
        "m4": {
            "value": "m1_4",
            "timestamp": "d4"
        }
    },
    "a1": {
        "a11": [

        ]
    },
    "m1": {},
    "comm1": "COMM1",
    "comm2": "COMM21529089656387",
    "share": "xxx",
    "share1": "yyy",
    "hub1": "h1",
    "hub2": "h2",
    "context": [

    ]
}
```

#### Flatten 1:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(data)])

 id class   owner metadata_m1_value metadata_m1_timestamp metadata_m2_value metadata_m2_timestamp metadata_m3_value metadata_m3_timestamp metadata_m4_value metadata_m4_timestamp  comm1               comm2 share share1 hub1 hub2
  1    c1  myself              m1_1                    d1              m1_2                    d2              m1_3                    d3              m1_4                    d4  COMM1  COMM21529089656387   xxx    yyy   h1   h2
```

---

#### Data 2:

```py
[{
        'accuracy': 17,
        'activity': [{
                'activity': [{
                        'confidence': 100,
                        'type': 'STILL'
                    }
                ],
                'timestampMs': '1542652'
            }
        ],
        'altitude': -10,
        'latitudeE7': 3777321,
        'longitudeE7': -122423125,
        'timestampMs': '1542654',
        'verticalAccuracy': 2
    }, {
        'accuracy': 17,
        'activity': [{
                'activity': [{
                        'confidence': 100,
                        'type': 'STILL'
                    }
                ],
                'timestampMs': '1542652'
            }
        ],
        'altitude': -10,
        'latitudeE7': 3777321,
        'longitudeE7': -122423125,
        'timestampMs': '1542654',
        'verticalAccuracy': 2
    }, {
        'accuracy': 17,
        'activity': [{
                'activity': [{
                        'confidence': 100,
                        'type': 'STILL'
                    }
                ],
                'timestampMs': '1542652'
            }
        ],
        'altitude': -10,
        'latitudeE7': 3777321,
        'longitudeE7': -122423125,
        'timestampMs': '1542654',
        'verticalAccuracy': 2
    }
]
```

#### Flatten 2:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data])

 accuracy  activity_0_activity_0_confidence activity_0_activity_0_type activity_0_timestampMs  altitude  latitudeE7  longitudeE7 timestampMs  verticalAccuracy
       17                               100                      STILL                1542652       -10     3777321   -122423125     1542654                 2
       17                               100                      STILL                1542652       -10     3777321   -122423125     1542654                 2
       17                               100                      STILL                1542652       -10     3777321   -122423125     1542654                 2
```

---

#### Data 3:

```py
{
    "1": {
        "VENUE": "JOEBURG",
        "COUNTRY": "HAE",
        "ITW": "XAD",
        "RACES": {
            "1": {
                "NO": 1,
                "TIME": "12:35"
            },
            "2": {
                "NO": 2,
                "TIME": "13:10"
            },
            "3": {
                "NO": 3,
                "TIME": "13:40"
            },
            "4": {
                "NO": 4,
                "TIME": "14:10"
            },
            "5": {
                "NO": 5,
                "TIME": "14:55"
            },
            "6": {
                "NO": 6,
                "TIME": "15:30"
            },
            "7": {
                "NO": 7,
                "TIME": "16:05"
            },
            "8": {
                "NO": 8,
                "TIME": "16:40"
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "VENUE": "FOOBURG",
        "COUNTRY": "ABA",
        "ITW": "XAD",
        "RACES": {
            "1": {
                "NO": 1,
                "TIME": "12:35"
            },
            "2": {
                "NO": 2,
                "TIME": "13:10"
            },
            "3": {
                "NO": 3,
                "TIME": "13:40"
            },
            "4": {
                "NO": 4,
                "TIME": "14:10"
            },
            "5": {
                "NO": 5,
                "TIME": "14:55"
            },
            "6": {
                "NO": 6,
                "TIME": "15:30"
            },
            "7": {
                "NO": 7,
                "TIME": "16:05"
            },
            "8": {
                "NO": 8,
                "TIME": "16:40"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Flatten 3:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(data[key]) for key in data])

   VENUE COUNTRY  ITW  RACES_1_NO RACES_1_TIME  RACES_2_NO RACES_2_TIME  RACES_3_NO RACES_3_TIME  RACES_4_NO RACES_4_TIME  RACES_5_NO RACES_5_TIME  RACES_6_NO RACES_6_TIME  RACES_7_NO RACES_7_TIME  RACES_8_NO RACES_8_TIME
 JOEBURG     HAE  XAD           1        12:35           2        13:10           3        13:40           4        14:10           5        14:55           6        15:30           7        16:05           8        16:40
 FOOBURG     ABA  XAD           1        12:35           2        13:10           3        13:40           4        14:10           5        14:55           6        15:30           7        16:05           8        16:40
```

---

### Other Examples:

1. [Python Pandas - Flatten Nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420863/python-pandas-flatten-nested-json/58006108#58006108)
2. [handling nested json in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331630/handling-nested-json-in-pandas/58005853#58005853)
3. [How to flatten a nested JSON from the NASA Weather Insight API in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295806/how-to-flatten-a-nested-json-from-the-nasa-weather-insight-api-in-python/58295889#58295889)