# How to loop through each element of my for loop to grab the values of this json?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

The json I'm trying to parse has a complex structure. Within the full list, there are 311 dictionaries, from which I managed to get some key values. However, within each of those 311 dictionaries, there is a key '`cadCargosFuncoes'`, whose value is a dictionary with one key, whose value is itself a list of dictionaries.

What I need is, for each of those 311 dictionaries of the json, grab the key value `'funDes'` within each of its `n` dictionaries, where `n` is not always the same, nor guaranteed to be different than zero.

I've tried to introduce a loop:

```
for i in ['cadCargosFuncoes']['pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosCargosFuncoes']`
```

in some different ways, but was never able to achieve what I need.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from csv import DictWriter

r = requests.get('http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e5276637939535a576470633352764a544977516d6c765a334c446f575a705932387657456c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657456c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXIII_json.txt&Inline=true')
r.raise_for_status()
data = r.json()

mps = data['RegistoBiografico']['RegistoBiograficoList']['pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb']

for j in mps:
    if 'cadProfissao' in j:
        pass
    else:
        j['cadProfissao'] = '-88'

for j in mps:
    if 'cadDtNascimento' in j:
        pass
    else:
        j['cadDtNascimento'] = '-88'

result = [{"ID": j["cadId"], "Nome": j["cadNomeCompleto"], "Sexo": j["cadSexo"], "D-Nasc": j["cadDtNascimento"], "Profissao": j["cadProfissao"]} for j in mps]

with open('bio_xiii.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, ('ID', 'Nome', 'Sexo', 'D-Nasc', 'Profissao'))
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Currently, my csv file has 311 rows, with `'cadId'`, `'cadNomeCompleto'`, `'cadSexo'`, `'cadDtNascimento'`, and `'cadProfissao'`. What I want is `m` additional columns, where `m` is the maximum number of dictionaries with the key `'funDes'` for those 311 dictionaries, such that each cell contains the value of `'funDes'` when such value exists, and `'-88'` when it doesn't exist (when it's either null or the maximum number of dictionaries with `'funDes'` is lower than `m`, for some of those 311 dictionaries).

Can someone give some advice on how to work this out?

Comment: You can use the following: [How to flatten nested JSON recursively, with flatten_json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442723/how-to-flatten-nested-json-recursively-with-flatten-json) with `df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data['RegistoBiografico']['RegistoBiograficoList']['pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb']])`.  This will return the flattened JSON in a pandas dataframe.  I tested it, so I know it works.  Then you can get your columns of interest.

Comment: You may also want `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 700)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This helps me a lot. However, now I have two additional problems, which I was trying to avoid by using ````DictWriter````. ````df```` is of class ````pandas.core.frame.DataFrame````, which requires something like ````df.to_csv('json_test.csv')```` to export to a csv file. However, when I do so, (1) the information appears all mixed up in a few cells and collumns, instead of the organizeed 311rx633cols, and (2) some names aren't exported properly - e.g. ADÃƒO JOSÃ‰ FONSECA SILVA instead of ADÃO JOSÉ FONSECA SILVA. What should I do differently here?

Comment: Maybe update pandas.  I'm on v25.2 I saved to_csv and brought it back with read_csv and, at least for that name, it imported as expected (e.g. `ADÃO JOSÉ FONSECA SILVA`).  A quick look at the csv, shows accented characters as they should be.  The df shows 633 columns by 311 rows as expected.

Comment: My version was, indeed, unupdated, but the problem persists - no accentuation and not one key per column. I now tried ````df.to_csv('bio_test.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1', sep=';')````, and python managed to correctly fill 5 rows - right accentuation and 1 key per column - before raising the following error: ````UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 3434: ordinal not in range(256)````. Is there some ````encoding```` value to deal with this? I'm very very new to python, so I don't even fully understand what the problem is...

Comment: Ok, i managed to do it with ````ExcelWriter```` :) :) thank you once again for all your help!