# How to extract all elements of a nested JSON?

Tags: python, json, csv, json-normalize

I am trying to convert the following JSON code in to a csv file and parsing the file via python.
I am not sure how do I go beyond "variants" section.

There are various array-lists that I have to read and most of the attributes are optional though.

Would like to see how effectively, I can read each attribute under each list so that I can write them as comma separated record into an output file which serves as input to my ETL processing load.

This is my code:

```
import json
with open(rb'E:\\ETL\\JaneM\\Test\\JaneM-PFFormattedTest.json', encoding="utf8") as pf:
    data = json.load(pf)
    for p in data["products"]:
        print(p['title'])
        print(p['admin_graphql_api_id'])
        for v in p["variants"]:
            print(v['id'])
        #for v in p{"Variants"}:
        #   print(v{product_id})
```

The below given snapshot is a JSON input file:

```py
{
   "products":[
      {      
         "id":1560417337456,
         "title":"\"Embrace The Good\" One Liner",
         "body_html":"\u003cp\u003eGive your day a boost with our “Embrace The Good” One Liner. Place this sign on a shelf or photo ledge for a daily encouragement to embrace the good in your life. This two-piece set includes a single acrylic cutout that rests in a wooden block.\u003c\/p\u003e",
         "vendor":"Julia Market",
         "product_type":"Accents",
         "created_at":"2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00",
         "handle":"embrace-the-good-one-liner",
         "updated_at":"2020-07-02T09:17:37-05:00",
         "published_at":"2019-09-27T14:17:37-05:00",
         "template_suffix":"",
         "published_scope":"global",
         "tags":"accents, all-products, bs-sale-2020, customtext2, gifts, gifts-for-friends, home-menu, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, Office, oos but not discontinued, sail-into-summer, September-sale, signs-decor-promo-2020, spring2019, standard discount collection",
         "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1560417337456",
         "variants":[
            {
               "id":15313179869296,
               "product_id":1560417337456,
               "title":"Default Title",
               "price":"15.00",
               "sku":"ONELINER-EMBRACE",
               "position":1,
               "inventory_policy":"deny",
               "compare_at_price":null,
               "fulfillment_service":"manual",
               "inventory_management":"shopify",
               "option1":"Default Title",
               "option2":null,
               "option3":null,
               "created_at":"2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00",
               "updated_at":"2020-07-02T09:17:37-05:00",
               "taxable":true,
               "barcode":"112019151733",
               "grams":181,
               "image_id":null,
               "weight":0.399,
               "weight_unit":"lb",
               "inventory_item_id":15437614448752,
               "inventory_quantity":51,
               "old_inventory_quantity":51,
               "tax_code":"",
               "requires_shipping":true,
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/15313179869296"
            }
         ],
         "options":[
            {
               "id":2125698269296,
               "product_id":1560417337456,
               "name":"Title",
               "position":1,
               "values":[
                  "Default Title"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "images":[
            {
               "id":4863201345587,
               "product_id":1560417337456,
               "position":1,
               "created_at":"2019-01-18T09:59:41-06:00",
               "updated_at":"2019-01-18T10:00:28-06:00",
               "alt":"acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says \"embrace the good\"",
               "width":2048,
               "height":2048,
               "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/embrace-the-good-one-liner-ONELINER-EMBRACE.jpg?v=1547827228",
               "variant_ids":[

               ],
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863201345587"
            },
            {
               "id":4863216975923,
               "product_id":1560417337456,
               "position":2,
               "created_at":"2019-01-18T10:09:15-06:00",
               "updated_at":"2019-01-18T10:09:23-06:00",
               "alt":"acrylic and wood quote sign",
               "width":2048,
               "height":2048,
               "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/acrylic-and-wood-one-liner.jpg?v=1547827763",
               "variant_ids":[

               ],
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863216975923"
            }
         ],
         "image":{
            "id":4863201345587,
            "product_id":1560417337456,
            "position":1,
            "created_at":"2019-01-18T09:59:41-06:00",
            "updated_at":"2019-01-18T10:00:28-06:00",
            "alt":"acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says \"embrace the good\"",
            "width":2048,
            "height":2048,
            "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/embrace-the-good-one-liner-ONELINER-EMBRACE.jpg?v=1547827228",
            "variant_ids":[

            ],
            "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863201345587"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":1560417370224,
         "title":"\"Be Brave\" One Liner",
         "body_html":"\u003cp\u003eEncourage yourself or a loved one to move past fear with our “Be Brave” One Liner. This two-piece set includes a single acrylic cutout of the phrase “Be Brave” that rests in a wooden block. Style this sign on a shelf, desk or photo ledge for daily encouragement.\u003c\/p\u003e",
         "vendor":"Magnolia Market",
         "product_type":"Accents",
         "created_at":"2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00",
         "handle":"be-brave-one-liner",
         "updated_at":"2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00",
         "published_at":"2019-09-27T14:17:37-05:00",
         "template_suffix":"",
         "published_scope":"global",
         "tags":"accents, all-products, bs-sale-2020, customtext2, madeinUSA, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, Office, oos but not discontinued, sail-into-summer, September-sale, signs-decor-promo-2020, spring2019, standard discount collection",
         "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1560417370224",
         "variants":[
            {
               "id":15313179934832,
               "product_id":1560417370224,
               "title":"Default Title",
               "price":"15.00",
               "sku":"ONELINER-BEBRAVE",
               "position":1,
               "inventory_policy":"deny",
               "compare_at_price":null,
               "fulfillment_service":"manual",
               "inventory_management":"shopify",
               "option1":"Default Title",
               "option2":null,
               "option3":null,
               "created_at":"2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00",
               "updated_at":"2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00",
               "taxable":true,
               "barcode":"112019151734",
               "grams":181,
               "image_id":null,
               "weight":0.399,
               "weight_unit":"lb",
               "inventory_item_id":15437614514288,
               "inventory_quantity":287,
               "old_inventory_quantity":287,
               "tax_code":"",
               "requires_shipping":true,
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/15313179934832"
            }
         ],
         "options":[
            {
               "id":2125698302064,
               "product_id":1560417370224,
               "name":"Title",
               "position":1,
               "values":[
                  "Default Title"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "images":[
            {
               "id":4863203147827,
               "product_id":1560417370224,
               "position":1,
               "created_at":"2019-01-18T10:01:42-06:00",
               "updated_at":"2019-01-18T10:01:56-06:00",
               "alt":"acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says \"be brave\"",
               "width":2048,
               "height":2048,
               "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/be-brave-one-liner-ONELINER-BEBRAVE.jpg?v=1547827316",
               "variant_ids":[

               ],
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863203147827"
            },
            {
               "id":4863214190643,
               "product_id":1560417370224,
               "position":2,
               "created_at":"2019-01-18T10:08:11-06:00",
               "updated_at":"2019-01-18T10:08:19-06:00",
               "alt":"acrylic and wood quote sign",
               "width":2048,
               "height":2048,
               "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/avrylic-and-wood-one-liner_706f5afb-14ef-4de7-b059-94db84baf12c.jpg?v=1547827699",
               "variant_ids":[

               ],
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863214190643"
            }
         ],
         "image":{
            "id":4863203147827,
            "product_id":1560417370224,
            "position":1,
            "created_at":"2019-01-18T10:01:42-06:00",
            "updated_at":"2019-01-18T10:01:56-06:00",
            "alt":"acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says \"be brave\"",
            "width":2048,
            "height":2048,
            "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/be-brave-one-liner-ONELINER-BEBRAVE.jpg?v=1547827316",
            "variant_ids":[

            ],
            "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863203147827"
         }
    }
    ,
    {
         "id":6332761412,
         "title":"\"Aww Shucks\" Greeting Card (INACTIVE)",
         "body_html":"",
         "vendor":"AH",
         "product_type":"Books + Paper",
         "created_at":"2016-07-29T09:07:36-05:00",
         "handle":"aww-shucks-greeting-card",
         "updated_at":"2020-06-08T00:05:37-05:00",
         "published_at":null,
         "template_suffix":"",
         "published_scope":"web",
         "tags":"lsob-10, standard discount collection",
         "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/6332761412",
         "variants":[
            {
               "id":21828312900,
               "product_id":6332761412,
               "title":"Default Title",
               "price":"4.50",
               "sku":"BD1615 (INACTIVE)",
               "position":1,
               "inventory_policy":"deny",
               "compare_at_price":null,
               "fulfillment_service":"manual",
               "inventory_management":"shopify",
               "option1":"Default Title",
               "option2":null,
               "option3":null,
               "created_at":"2016-07-29T09:07:36-05:00",
               "updated_at":"2020-03-10T15:11:49-05:00",
               "taxable":true,
               "barcode":null,
               "grams":0,
               "image_id":null,
               "weight":0.0,
               "weight_unit":"g",
               "inventory_item_id":16074523204,
               "inventory_quantity":0,
               "old_inventory_quantity":0,
               "tax_code":"",
               "requires_shipping":true,
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/21828312900"
            }
         ],
         "options":[
            {
               "id":7615401988,
               "product_id":6332761412,
               "name":"Title",
               "position":1,
               "values":[
                  "Default Title"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "images":[
            {
               "id":14530688388,
               "product_id":6332761412,
               "position":1,
               "created_at":"2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00",
               "updated_at":"2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00",
               "alt":null,
               "width":140,
               "height":180,
               "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/Screenshot_2016-07-28_16.24.39.png?v=1469801258",
               "variant_ids":[

               ],
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/14530688388"
            }
         ],
         "image":{
            "id":14530688388,
            "product_id":6332761412,
            "position":1,
            "created_at":"2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00",
            "updated_at":"2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00",
            "alt":null,
            "width":140,
            "height":180,
            "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/Screenshot_2016-07-28_16.24.39.png?v=1469801258",
            "variant_ids":[

            ],
            "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/14530688388"
         }
      }
      ,
      {
         "id":1055314692,
         "title":"\"It is Well\" Shiplap Sign",
         "body_html":"\u003cp\u003eOur \"It is Well\" Shiplap Sign comes in two sizes and features the title of one of the most influential hymns ever written, which was originally published in the 1800s. Made right here in Texas, the sign is distressed and weathered to give it character of a relic that has endured the test of time.\u003c\/p\u003e",
         "vendor":"8FD",
         "product_type":"Wall Decor",
         "created_at":"2015-08-05T15:10:42-05:00",
         "handle":"it-is-well-ship-lap-sign",
         "updated_at":"2020-06-28T02:59:21-05:00",
         "published_at":null,
         "template_suffix":"",
         "published_scope":"web",
         "tags":"discontinued:number:1, flow:oos, ios-hidden, lsob-10, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, standard discount collection, unpublish-app",
         "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1055314692",
         "variants":[
            {
               "id":44383342724,
               "product_id":1055314692,
               "title":"Large",
               "price":"75.00",
               "sku":"WellSign15",
               "position":1,
               "inventory_policy":"deny",
               "compare_at_price":"125.00",
               "fulfillment_service":"manual",
               "inventory_management":"shopify",
               "option1":"Large",
               "option2":null,
               "option3":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-03T14:56:06-05:00",
               "updated_at":"2020-06-28T02:59:21-05:00",
               "taxable":true,
               "barcode":"132017039159",
               "grams":4536,
               "image_id":null,
               "weight":10.0002,
               "weight_unit":"lb",
               "inventory_item_id":32807497988,
               "inventory_quantity":0,
               "old_inventory_quantity":0,
               "tax_code":"",
               "requires_shipping":true,
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/44383342724"
            },
            {
               "id":4047331332,
               "product_id":1055314692,
               "title":"Small",
               "price":"46.80",
               "sku":"WellSign15-S",
               "position":2,
               "inventory_policy":"deny",
               "compare_at_price":"78.00",
               "fulfillment_service":"manual",
               "inventory_management":"shopify",
               "option1":"Small",
               "option2":null,
               "option3":null,
               "created_at":"2015-08-05T15:10:42-05:00",
               "updated_at":"2020-06-28T02:59:21-05:00",
               "taxable":true,
               "barcode":"132017039160",
               "grams":4536,
               "image_id":27157975492,
               "weight":10.0002,
               "weight_unit":"lb",
               "inventory_item_id":6752772100,
               "inventory_quantity":0,
               "old_inventory_quantity":0,
               "tax_code":"",
               "requires_shipping":true,
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/4047331332"
            }
         ],
         "options":[
            {
               "id":1325397124,
               "product_id":1055314692,
               "name":"Size",
               "position":1,
               "values":[
                  "Large",
                  "Small"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "images":[
            {
               "id":27157975492,
               "product_id":1055314692,
               "position":1,
               "created_at":"2017-07-03T14:59:42-05:00",
               "updated_at":"2019-11-22T16:46:38-06:00",
               "alt":"\"It is Well\" Shiplap Sign",
               "width":600,
               "height":600,
               "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/001_PRD_2017_06_20-117_grande_22e04f4b-e74d-4a12-9f74-0c91f25dc633.jpg?v=1574462798",
               "variant_ids":[
                  4047331332
               ],
               "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/27157975492"
            }
         ],
         "image":{
            "id":27157975492,
            "product_id":1055314692,
            "position":1,
            "created_at":"2017-07-03T14:59:42-05:00",
            "updated_at":"2019-11-22T16:46:38-06:00",
            "alt":"\"It is Well\" Shiplap Sign",
            "width":600,
            "height":600,
            "src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/001_PRD_2017_06_20-117_grande_22e04f4b-e74d-4a12-9f74-0c91f25dc633.jpg?v=1574462798",
            "variant_ids":[
               4047331332
            ],
            "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/27157975492"
         }
      }
]
}
```

Following error is thrown while running the below given code with full volume of JSON data file

```py
PS C:\Users\marunachalam> & python c:/Users/marunachalam/Downloads/Extract-ProductFeed.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/marunachalam/Downloads/Extract-ProductFeed.py", line 16, in <module>
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode()).reset_index(drop=True)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6878, in apply        
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 186, in get_result    
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 316, in apply_standard
    return self.wrap_results(results, res_index)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 354, in wrap_results
    return self.wrap_results_for_axis(results, res_index)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 396, in wrap_results_for_axis     
    result = self.obj._constructor(data=results)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 435, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 254, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 69, in arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 311, in _homogenize
    val = val.reindex(index, copy=False)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4030, in reindex
    return super().reindex(index=index, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4544, in reindex
    axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4567, in _reindex_axes
    allow_dups=False,
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4613, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy,
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1251, in reindex_indexer
    self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)
  File "C:\Users\marunachalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3099, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Also see [How to flatten nested JSON recursively, with flatten_json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442723) for additional details with a recursive approach.

  - To use this function, `flat_data_dict = flatten_json(data)`
- This will result in a `dict` which can be saved to `csv` by using [SO: How do I write a Python dictionary to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)

```
def flatten_json(nested_json: dict, exclude: list=[''], sep: str='_') -> dict:
    """
    Flatten a list of nested dicts.
    """
    out = dict()
    def flatten(x: (list, dict, str), name: str='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    flatten(x[a], f'{name}{a}{sep}')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}{sep}')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out


df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data['products']])
```

### df

```py
              id                                  title                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          body_html           vendor   product_type                 created_at                      handle                 updated_at               published_at template_suffix published_scope                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              tags                     admin_graphql_api_id   variants_0_id  variants_0_product_id variants_0_title variants_0_price     variants_0_sku  variants_0_position variants_0_inventory_policy variants_0_compare_at_price variants_0_fulfillment_service variants_0_inventory_management variants_0_option1 variants_0_option2 variants_0_option3      variants_0_created_at      variants_0_updated_at  variants_0_taxable variants_0_barcode  variants_0_grams variants_0_image_id  variants_0_weight variants_0_weight_unit  variants_0_inventory_item_id  variants_0_inventory_quantity  variants_0_old_inventory_quantity variants_0_tax_code  variants_0_requires_shipping                  variants_0_admin_graphql_api_id   options_0_id  options_0_product_id options_0_name  options_0_position options_0_values_0    images_0_id  images_0_product_id  images_0_position        images_0_created_at        images_0_updated_at                                                       images_0_alt  images_0_width  images_0_height                                                                                                                                       images_0_src                 images_0_admin_graphql_api_id   images_1_id  images_1_product_id  images_1_position        images_1_created_at        images_1_updated_at                 images_1_alt  images_1_width  images_1_height                                                                                                                                    images_1_src                 images_1_admin_graphql_api_id       image_id  image_product_id  image_position           image_created_at           image_updated_at                                                          image_alt  image_width  image_height                                                                                                                                          image_src                    image_admin_graphql_api_id  variants_1_id  variants_1_product_id variants_1_title variants_1_price variants_1_sku  variants_1_position variants_1_inventory_policy variants_1_compare_at_price variants_1_fulfillment_service variants_1_inventory_management variants_1_option1  variants_1_option2  variants_1_option3      variants_1_created_at      variants_1_updated_at variants_1_taxable variants_1_barcode  variants_1_grams  variants_1_image_id  variants_1_weight variants_1_weight_unit  variants_1_inventory_item_id  variants_1_inventory_quantity  variants_1_old_inventory_quantity variants_1_tax_code variants_1_requires_shipping              variants_1_admin_graphql_api_id options_0_values_1  images_0_variant_ids_0  image_variant_ids_0
0  1560417337456           "Embrace The Good" One Liner                                                       <p>Give your day a boost with our “Embrace The Good” One Liner. Place this sign on a shelf or photo ledge for a daily encouragement to embrace the good in your life. This two-piece set includes a single acrylic cutout that rests in a wooden block.<\/p>     Julia Market        Accents  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00  embrace-the-good-one-liner  2020-07-02T09:17:37-05:00  2019-09-27T14:17:37-05:00                          global  accents, all-products, bs-sale-2020, customtext2, gifts, gifts-for-friends, home-menu, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, Office, oos but not discontinued, sail-into-summer, September-sale, signs-decor-promo-2020, spring2019, standard discount collection  gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1560417337456  15313179869296          1560417337456    Default Title            15.00   ONELINER-EMBRACE                    1                        deny                        None                         manual                         shopify      Default Title               None               None  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00  2020-07-02T09:17:37-05:00                True       112019151733               181                None             0.3990                     lb                15437614448752                             51                                 51                                              True  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/15313179869296  2125698269296         1560417337456          Title                   1      Default Title  4863201345587        1560417337456                  1  2019-01-18T09:59:41-06:00  2019-01-18T10:00:28-06:00  acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says "embrace the good"            2048             2048                         https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/embrace-the-good-one-liner-ONELINER-EMBRACE.jpg?v=1547827228  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863201345587  4.863217e+12         1.560417e+12                2.0  2019-01-18T10:09:15-06:00  2019-01-18T10:09:23-06:00  acrylic and wood quote sign          2048.0           2048.0                                       https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/acrylic-and-wood-one-liner.jpg?v=1547827763  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863216975923  4863201345587     1560417337456               1  2019-01-18T09:59:41-06:00  2019-01-18T10:00:28-06:00  acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says "embrace the good"         2048          2048                         https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/embrace-the-good-one-liner-ONELINER-EMBRACE.jpg?v=1547827228  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863201345587            NaN                    NaN              NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN                         NaN                         NaN                            NaN                             NaN                NaN                 NaN                 NaN                        NaN                        NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN                  NaN                NaN                    NaN                           NaN                            NaN                                NaN                 NaN                          NaN                                          NaN                NaN                     NaN                  NaN
1  1560417370224                   "Be Brave" One Liner                                     <p>Encourage yourself or a loved one to move past fear with our “Be Brave” One Liner. This two-piece set includes a single acrylic cutout of the phrase “Be Brave” that rests in a wooden block. Style this sign on a shelf, desk or photo ledge for daily encouragement.<\/p>  Magnolia Market        Accents  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00          be-brave-one-liner  2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00  2019-09-27T14:17:37-05:00                          global                            accents, all-products, bs-sale-2020, customtext2, madeinUSA, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, Office, oos but not discontinued, sail-into-summer, September-sale, signs-decor-promo-2020, spring2019, standard discount collection  gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1560417370224  15313179934832          1560417370224    Default Title            15.00   ONELINER-BEBRAVE                    1                        deny                        None                         manual                         shopify      Default Title               None               None  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00  2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00                True       112019151734               181                None             0.3990                     lb                15437614514288                            287                                287                                              True  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/15313179934832  2125698302064         1560417370224          Title                   1      Default Title  4863203147827        1560417370224                  1  2019-01-18T10:01:42-06:00  2019-01-18T10:01:56-06:00          acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says "be brave"            2048             2048                                 https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/be-brave-one-liner-ONELINER-BEBRAVE.jpg?v=1547827316  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863203147827  4.863214e+12         1.560417e+12                2.0  2019-01-18T10:08:11-06:00  2019-01-18T10:08:19-06:00  acrylic and wood quote sign          2048.0           2048.0  https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/avrylic-and-wood-one-liner_706f5afb-14ef-4de7-b059-94db84baf12c.jpg?v=1547827699  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863214190643  4863203147827     1560417370224               1  2019-01-18T10:01:42-06:00  2019-01-18T10:01:56-06:00          acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says "be brave"         2048          2048                                 https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/be-brave-one-liner-ONELINER-BEBRAVE.jpg?v=1547827316  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/4863203147827            NaN                    NaN              NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN                         NaN                         NaN                            NaN                             NaN                NaN                 NaN                 NaN                        NaN                        NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN                  NaN                NaN                    NaN                           NaN                            NaN                                NaN                 NaN                          NaN                                          NaN                NaN                     NaN                  NaN
2     6332761412  "Aww Shucks" Greeting Card (INACTIVE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  AH  Books + Paper  2016-07-29T09:07:36-05:00    aww-shucks-greeting-card  2020-06-08T00:05:37-05:00                       None                             web                                                                                                                                                                                                                             lsob-10, standard discount collection     gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/6332761412     21828312900             6332761412    Default Title             4.50  BD1615 (INACTIVE)                    1                        deny                        None                         manual                         shopify      Default Title               None               None  2016-07-29T09:07:36-05:00  2020-03-10T15:11:49-05:00                True               None                 0                None             0.0000                      g                   16074523204                              0                                  0                                              True     gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/21828312900     7615401988            6332761412          Title                   1      Default Title    14530688388           6332761412                  1  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00                                                               None             140              180                                      https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/Screenshot_2016-07-28_16.24.39.png?v=1469801258    gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/14530688388           NaN                  NaN                NaN                        NaN                        NaN                          NaN             NaN              NaN                                                                                                                                             NaN                                           NaN    14530688388        6332761412               1  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00                                                               None          140           180                                      https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/Screenshot_2016-07-28_16.24.39.png?v=1469801258    gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/14530688388            NaN                    NaN              NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN                         NaN                         NaN                            NaN                             NaN                NaN                 NaN                 NaN                        NaN                        NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN                  NaN                NaN                    NaN                           NaN                            NaN                                NaN                 NaN                          NaN                                          NaN                NaN                     NaN                  NaN
3     1055314692              "It is Well" Shiplap Sign  <p>Our "It is Well" Shiplap Sign comes in two sizes and features the title of one of the most influential hymns ever written, which was originally published in the 1800s. Made right here in Texas, the sign is distressed and weathered to give it character of a relic that has endured the test of time.<\/p>              8FD     Wall Decor  2015-08-05T15:10:42-05:00    it-is-well-ship-lap-sign  2020-06-28T02:59:21-05:00                       None                             web                                                                                                                            discontinued:number:1, flow:oos, ios-hidden, lsob-10, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, standard discount collection, unpublish-app     gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1055314692     44383342724             1055314692            Large            75.00         WellSign15                    1                        deny                      125.00                         manual                         shopify              Large               None               None  2017-07-03T14:56:06-05:00  2020-06-28T02:59:21-05:00                True       132017039159              4536                None            10.0002                     lb                   32807497988                              0                                  0                                              True     gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/44383342724     1325397124            1055314692           Size                   1              Large    27157975492           1055314692                  1  2017-07-03T14:59:42-05:00  2019-11-22T16:46:38-06:00                                          "It is Well" Shiplap Sign             600              600  https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/001_PRD_2017_06_20-117_grande_22e04f4b-e74d-4a12-9f74-0c91f25dc633.jpg?v=1574462798    gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/27157975492           NaN                  NaN                NaN                        NaN                        NaN                          NaN             NaN              NaN                                                                                                                                             NaN                                           NaN    27157975492        1055314692               1  2017-07-03T14:59:42-05:00  2019-11-22T16:46:38-06:00                                          "It is Well" Shiplap Sign          600           600  https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/001_PRD_2017_06_20-117_grande_22e04f4b-e74d-4a12-9f74-0c91f25dc633.jpg?v=1574462798    gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/27157975492   4.047331e+09           1.055315e+09            Small            46.80   WellSign15-S                  2.0                        deny                       78.00                         manual                         shopify              Small                 NaN                 NaN  2015-08-05T15:10:42-05:00  2020-06-28T02:59:21-05:00               True       132017039160            4536.0         2.715798e+10            10.0002                     lb                  6.752772e+09                            0.0                                0.0                                             True  gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/4047331332              Small            4.047331e+09         4.047331e+09
```

---

- This option worked with the original data, but not the updated data.
- Use `pandas.json_normalize` to parse the `dict`
- Some columns contain `lists` of `dicts`, which need to be exploded with `pandas.Series.explode`, so each `dict` is a separate row.

  - Exploding multiple columns at once, as shown below, only works if the `lists` in the columns are of equal length.

    - If the `lists` are not the same length, `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` occurs.
- Use `json_normalize` on any additional columns of `dicts`
- Use `pandas.concat` to combine `df` and the dataframes in `normalized`, into a single dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read data as shown in the question
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'products')

# expand any lists; only works if the list in the columns are all of equal length
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode()).reset_index(drop=True)

# normalize the columns of dicts into a list of dataframe
columns_of_dicts = ['variants', 'options', 'images']
normalize = [pd.json_normalize(df[col]) for col in columns_of_dicts]

# combine all of the dataframes into a single dataframe
df = pd.concat([df] + normalize, axis=1).drop(columns=columns_of_dicts).reset_index(drop=True)

# explode any new lists; in this case variant_ids
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode()).reset_index(drop=True)

# save to a csv
df.to_csv('my_json_data.csv', index=False)
```

#### `display(df)`

```
               id                                title                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       body_html         vendor   product_type                 created_at                    handle                 updated_at               published_at template_suffix published_scope                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    tags                    admin_graphql_api_id       image.id image.product_id  image.position           image.created_at           image.updated_at                                                  image.alt  image.width  image.height                                                                                                          image.src image.variant_ids                   image.admin_graphql_api_id              id     product_id          title  price                sku  position inventory_policy compare_at_price fulfillment_service inventory_management        option1 option2 option3                 created_at                 updated_at  taxable       barcode  grams image_id  weight weight_unit  inventory_item_id  inventory_quantity  old_inventory_quantity tax_code  requires_shipping                            admin_graphql_api_id             id     product_id   name  position         values             id     product_id  position                 created_at                 updated_at                                                        alt  width  height                                                                                                                                            src variant_ids                         admin_graphql_api_id
0  abab6332761412  "Aww Scks" Greeting Card (INACTIVE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             AH  Books + Paper  2016-07-29T09:07:36-05:00  aww-shucks-greeting-card  2020-06-08T00:05:37-05:00                       None                             web                                                                                                                                                                                                   lsob-10, standard discount collection   gid:\/\/verify\/Product\/ab6332761412    14530688388     ab6332761412               1  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00                                                       None          140           180       https:\/\/cdn.verify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/Screenshot_2016-07-28_16.24.39.png?v=1469801258               NaN    gid:\/\/verify\/ProductImage\/14530688388     21828312900   ab6332761412  Default Title   4.50  BD1615 (INACTIVE)         1             deny             None              manual               verify  Default Title    None    None  2016-07-29T09:07:36-05:00  2020-03-10T15:11:49-05:00     True          None      0     None   0.000           g        16074523204                   0                       0                        True     gid:\/\/verify\/ProductVariant\/21828312900     7615401988   ab6332761412  Title         1  Default Title    14530688388   ab6332761412         1  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00  2016-07-29T09:07:38-05:00                                                       None    140     180                                   https:\/\/cdn.verify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/Screenshot_2016-07-28_16.24.39.png?v=1469801258         NaN    gid:\/\/verify\/ProductImage\/14530688388
1   1560417370224                 "Be Brave" One Liner  <p>Encourage yourself or a loved one to move past fear with our “Be Brave” One Liner. This two-piece set includes a single acrylic cutout of the phrase “Be Brave” that rests in a wooden block. Style this sign on a shelf, desk or photo ledge for daily encouragement.<\/p>  Jane M Market        Accents  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00        be-brave-one-liner  2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00  2019-09-27T14:17:37-05:00                          global  accents, all-products, bs-sale-2020, customtext2, madeinUSA, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, Office, oos but not discontinued, sail-into-summer, September-sale, signs-decor-promo-2020, spring2019, standard discount collection  gid:\/\/verify\/Product\/1560417370224  4863203147827    1560417370224               1  2019-01-18T10:01:42-06:00  2019-01-18T10:01:56-06:00  acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says "be brave"         2048          2048  https:\/\/cdn.verify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/be-brave-one-liner-ONELINER-BEBRAVE.jpg?v=1547827316               NaN  gid:\/\/verify\/ProductImage\/4863203147827  15313179934832  1560417370224  Default Title  15.00   ONELINER-BEBRAVE         1             deny             None              manual               verify  Default Title    None    None  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00  2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00     True  112019151734    181     None   0.399          lb     15437614514288                 287                     287                        True  gid:\/\/verify\/ProductVariant\/15313179934832  2125698302064  1560417370224  Title         1  Default Title  4863203147827  1560417370224         1  2019-01-18T10:01:42-06:00  2019-01-18T10:01:56-06:00  acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says "be brave"   2048    2048                              https:\/\/cdn.verify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/be-brave-one-liner-ONELINER-BEBRAVE.jpg?v=1547827316         NaN  gid:\/\/verify\/ProductImage\/4863203147827
2   1560417370224                 "Be Brave" One Liner  <p>Encourage yourself or a loved one to move past fear with our “Be Brave” One Liner. This two-piece set includes a single acrylic cutout of the phrase “Be Brave” that rests in a wooden block. Style this sign on a shelf, desk or photo ledge for daily encouragement.<\/p>  Jane M Market        Accents  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00        be-brave-one-liner  2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00  2019-09-27T14:17:37-05:00                          global  accents, all-products, bs-sale-2020, customtext2, madeinUSA, netsuite-shipping_category-standard, Office, oos but not discontinued, sail-into-summer, September-sale, signs-decor-promo-2020, spring2019, standard discount collection  gid:\/\/verify\/Product\/1560417370224  4863203147827    1560417370224               1  2019-01-18T10:01:42-06:00  2019-01-18T10:01:56-06:00  acrylic quote sign with wooden stand that says "be brave"         2048          2048  https:\/\/cdn.verify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/be-brave-one-liner-ONELINER-BEBRAVE.jpg?v=1547827316               NaN  gid:\/\/verify\/ProductImage\/4863203147827  15313179934832  1560417370224  Default Title  15.00   ONELINER-BEBRAVE         1             deny             None              manual               verify  Default Title    None    None  2018-11-01T14:11:23-05:00  2020-07-02T08:57:29-05:00     True  112019151734    181     None   0.399          lb     15437614514288                 287                     287                        True  gid:\/\/verify\/ProductVariant\/15313179934832  2125698302064  1560417370224  Title         1  Default Title  4863214190643  1560417370224         2  2019-01-18T10:08:11-06:00  2019-01-18T10:08:19-06:00                                acrylic and wood quote sign   2048    2048  https:\/\/cdn.verify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0207\/8508\/products\/avrylic-and-wood-one-liner_706f5afb-14ef-4de7-b059-94db84baf12c.jpg?v=1547827699         NaN  gid:\/\/verify\/ProductImage\/4863214190643
```

- Notice there are two rows for `'id'` `4863203147827`

  - This occurred because the `'images'` key had a `list` with 2 `dicts`, which were expanded to separate rows.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the flatten_json code you gave and it converted the full volume file into csv successfully. THANKs