# Flattening nested JSON to pandas.DataFrame: Ordering and Naming Columns based on dictionary values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, nested

My question raised when I exploited [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185753/3888115) provided by Trenton McKinney on the issue of flattening multiple nested JSON-files for handling in pandas.
Following his advice, I have used the [`flatten_json` function described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442723/how-to-flatten-a-nested-json-recursively-with-flatten-json) to flatten a batch of nested json files. **However, I have run into a problem with the uniformity of my JSON-files.**

A single JSON-File looks roughly like this made-up example data:

```
{
    "product": "example_productname",
    "product_id": "example_productid",
    "product_type": "example_producttype",
    "producer": "example_producer",
    "currency": "example_currency",
    "client_id": "example_clientid",
    "supplement": [
        {
            "supplementtype": "RTZ",
            "price": 300000,
            "rebate": "500",
        },
        {
            "supplementtype": "CVB",
            "price": 500000,
            "rebate": "250",
        },
        {
            "supplementtype": "JKL",
            "price": 100000,
            "rebate": "750",
        },
    ],
}
```

Utilizing the referenced code, I will end up with data looking like this:

| product | product_id | product_type | producer | currency | client_id | supplement_0_supplementtype | supplement_0_price | supplement_0_rebate | supplement_1_supplementtype | supplement_1_price | supplement_1_rebate | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example_productname | example_productid | example_type | example_producer | example_currency | example_clientid | RTZ | 300000 | 500 | CVB | 500000 | 250 | etc |
| example_productname2 | example_productid2 | example_type2 | example_producer2 | example_currency2 | example_clientid2 | CVB | 500000 | 250 | RTZ | 300000 | 500 | etc |

**There are multiple issues with this**.
Firstly, in my data, there is a limited list of "supplements", however, they do not always appear, and if they do, they are not always in the same order. *In the example table, you can see that the two "supplements" switched positions in the second row. I would prefer a fixed order of the "supplement columns".*

Secondly, the best option would be a table like this:

| product | product_id | product_type | producer | currency | client_id | supplement_RTZ_price | supplement_RTZ_rebate | supplement_CVB_price | supplement_CVB_rebate | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example_productname | example_productid | example_type | example_producer | example_currency | example_clientid | 300000 | 500 | 500000 | 250 | etc |

I have tried editing the `flatten_json` function referenced, but I don't have an inkling of how to make this work.
**The solution consists of simply editing the dictionary (thanks to Andrej Kesely)**. I just added a pass to exceptions in case some columns are inexistent.

```
d = {
    "product": "example_productname",
    "product_id": "example_productid",
    "product_type": "example_producttype",
    "producer": "example_producer",
    "currency": "example_currency",
    "client_id": "example_clientid",
    "supplement": [
        {
            "supplementtype": "RTZ",
            "price": 300000,
            "rebate": "500",
        },
        {
            "supplementtype": "CVB",
            "price": 500000,
            "rebate": "250",
        },
        {
            "supplementtype": "JKL",
            "price": 100000,
            "rebate": "750",
        },
    ],
}

for s in d["supplement"]:
    try:
        d["supplementtype_{}_price".format(s["supplementtype"])] = s["price"]
    except:
        pass
    try:
        d["supplementtype_{}_rebate".format(s["supplementtype"])] = s["rebate"]
    except:
        pass

del d["supplement"]

df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
               product         product_id         product_type          producer          currency         client_id  supplementtype_RTZ_price supplementtype_RTZ_rebate  supplementtype_CVB_price supplementtype_CVB_rebate  supplementtype_JKL_price supplementtype_JKL_rebate
0  example_productname  example_productid  example_producttype  example_producer  example_currency  example_clientid                    300000                       500                    500000                       250                    100000                       750
```

**The used/referenced code**:

```
def flatten_json(nested_json: dict, exclude: list=[''], sep: str='_') -> dict:
    """
    Flatten a list of nested dicts.
    """
    out = dict()
    def flatten(x: (list, dict, str), name: str='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    flatten(x[a], f'{name}{a}{sep}')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}{sep}')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out

# list of files
files = ['test1.json', 'test2.json']

# list to add dataframe from each file
df_list = list()

# iterate through files
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:

        # read with json
        data = json.loads(f.read())

        # flatten_json into a dataframe and add to the dataframe list
        df_list.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(flatten_json(data), orient='index').T)
        
# concat all dataframes together
df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with making the tables work, Tomerikoo. Mind sharing why they rendered in the preview, but not in the actual post? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the dictionary before you create dataframe from it:

```
d = {
    "product": "example_productname",
    "product_id": "example_productid",
    "product_type": "example_producttype",
    "producer": "example_producer",
    "currency": "example_currency",
    "client_id": "example_clientid",
    "supplement": [
        {
            "supplementtype": "RTZ",
            "price": 300000,
            "rebate": "500",
        },
        {
            "supplementtype": "CVB",
            "price": 500000,
            "rebate": "250",
        },
        {
            "supplementtype": "JKL",
            "price": 100000,
            "rebate": "750",
        },
    ],
}

for s in d["supplement"]:
    d["supplementtype_{}_price".format(s["supplementtype"])] = s["price"]
    d["supplementtype_{}_rebate".format(s["supplementtype"])] = s["rebate"]

del d["supplement"]

df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               product         product_id         product_type          producer          currency         client_id  supplementtype_RTZ_price supplementtype_RTZ_rebate  supplementtype_CVB_price supplementtype_CVB_rebate  supplementtype_JKL_price supplementtype_JKL_rebate
0  example_productname  example_productid  example_producttype  example_producer  example_currency  example_clientid                    300000                       500                    500000                       250                    100000                       750
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an easy solution. I have slightly adjusted it to run even when one of the "supplement"-columns is inexistent, and updated my question with it.
I guess I have a lot to learn about dictionaries/python data management.