# apply regex to extract a set of character within square and curly braces

Tags: python, regex

I have to process some json file in order to flatten it. I am facing challenge in capturing some text pattern using regex, as general flatten libraries won't work on my file.
I have to capture `","` from within [{"sometext","more_text"}] text in order to replace it with `\",\"`.
I tried a lot but cant capture `","` my current regex that captures entire bracket text is

```
\[\{".*?\}\]
```

Sample json

```
{"action":"add","actions":[{"country","IND"}],"ctx":"{\"charset\":\"UTF-8\",\"client_id\":\"G9.2.2045341156.1629864410\",\"cookie\":\"1\",\"domain_user\":\"28f51979-bef8-4731-b242-e3a00496d9ba\",\"fp\":\"659810303\",\"id\":\"d368f505-6226-4650-aeba-caf9fb18fc53\",\"page_res\":\"478x4952\",\"refr\"
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/vcjPQx/1

Regex should be able to select only one occurance of `","` that comes inside square bracket and curly braces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten a nested JSON recursively, with flatten\_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442723/how-to-flatten-a-nested-json-recursively-with-flatten-json)

Comment: ... both files are NOT valid json, they are concatenation of JSON strings ... there is even multiple JSON per line ...

Comment: So I won't help because I don't want to deal with such bad content, but don't use regex : use json.loads and json.dumps to pass from python structure to string please

Comment: @anotherGatsby unfortunately my file is not in a format expected by flatten_json library

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern

```
(\[\{[^\{\[\]\}]*)(\",\")([^\[\]\{\}]*\}\])
```

which contains 3 capturing groups. We copy the 1st and 3rd as found and use the pattern.

```
\1\\\",\\\"\3
```

which replaces each `","` with `\",\"` .
We use `\1` and `\3` to copy the 1st and 3rd capturing groups.

https://regex101.com/r/aNHZ04/2

Comment: This will not work as I don't want to replace all character (\",\") but only those falling within square and curly braces represented by regex \[\{".*?\}\].

Answer (score 0):

Hit, If understood your problem correctly, I think this regex is your solution:

```
/{\s*\"[^"]+\"\s*(,)\s*\"[^"]+\"\s*}/gm
```

See Test results:
https://regex101.com/r/y4ocUT/1